# Can't build chart from simple values on page

Tags: jquery, charts

I'm trying to build a chart based on the values on this stress test (2nd page - you can just click next as I havent set any of the questions as mandatory), however I cant seem to create the chart from the list of values that are calculated.  I tried using JQplot but cant seem to get it to work....

Link is below.

http://www.beatinganger.com/stress-test

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated.

Comment: If you aren't married to the idea of using JQplot, I've always found http://highcharts.com api super easy to use and the charts look good too.  Might be overkill for what you're looking for, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer" but you have not included the file "jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js". That is the problem. According to [this](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/categoryAxisTests.php) you have to include that file in order to use "categoryAxisRenderer".